# Create view by joining three tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables STUDENTS, SUBJECTS, RANK ,with data as -

1) `STUDENTS` [`NAME`(Primary)]

```
NAME
--------
Alex
Greg
```

2) `SUBJECTS` [`ID`(Primary)]:

```
ID
--------
100
101
102
```

3) `RANK` [`SEQ`(Primary), `NAME`, `ID`, `RANK`]

```
SEQ    NAME    ID     RANK
------ ------- ------ ------
1      Alex    100    A 
2      Greg    100    A 
3      Greg    101    B
```

I want to create a view that should display data as

```
NAME    ID     RANK
------- ------ ------
Alex    100    A
Alex    101    Z
Alex    102    Z
Greg    100    A
Greg    101    B
Greg    102    Z
```

So, for every student and for every subject, the View should display the `RANK` if present in `RANK` table, else replace the `NULL` with `'Z'`.

I'm a newbie to SQL. So any help in forming the query would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you have written so far.

Comment: This smells like homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cross join `student` and `subject` then left outer join the result with `rank` to get ranks for all (student, subject) combination. selecting column with `NVL` OR `COALESCE` will replace `NULL` with 'z'.

```
SELECT st.name,
       su.id,
       NVL(ra.rank,'Z')           Rank, --COALESCE(ra.rank,'Z') Rank
FROM   student st
       CROSS JOIN subject su
       LEFT OUTER JOIN rank ra
                    ON ra.name = st.name
                       AND ra.id = su.id
ORDER  BY st.name,su.id
```

Note : ORDER BY can be removed from above query if you don't need.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fca2d/9)

Comment: You could also change the `CASE` statement and use `NVL(ra.rank,'Z'),`

Comment: thanks for noticing. :) either `coalesce` or `nvl` can also do it and seems better.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.NAME, r.ID, NVL(r.RANK, 'Z')
FROM RANK r, studendts st, SUBJECTS su
WHERE st. NAME = r. NAME
AND   su.ID = r.ID
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```